# \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} font incorrect

Tags: fonts

I have the below code and would like the main body text to be Times New Roman (which i think I have managed by specifying the `fontfamily` as `ptm` in each section) and the section headings and sub-headings to be Arial 12. I know Arial cannot be used, so I have set the main font to Helvetica using `\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}` however this does not appear to get applied to my sections when I use `\renewcommand`.

I know this should be easy, and I've tried to follow a few other posts but struggling to apply to my setup. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tmargin=1.25in,bmargin=1.25in,lmargin=1.5in,rmargin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % Arial

\begin{document}
\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\sffamily
\noindent\rule{14cm}{1pt}
\begin{center}
\huge{\textbf{Title is using correct font}}
\par
\vspace{7mm}
\end{center}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\noindent\rule{14cm}{1pt}
\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
\begin{flushleft}

\vspace{7mm}
\par
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\large{\textbf{ABSTRACT should be arial 12}}}
\sfdefault
\par
\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
\vspace{7mm}
\par
Correctly using  Times New Roman 11
\vspace{7mm}
\par
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\large{\textbf{1 \quad \quad INTRODUCTION should be arial 12}}}
\sfdefault
\par
\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
\vspace{7mm}
\par
Correctly using  Times New Roman 11
\vspace{7mm}
\par

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\large{\textbf{2 \quad \quad METHODOLOGY should be arial 12}}}
\sfdefault
\par
\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
\vspace{7mm}
\par
Correctly using  Times New Roman 11
\vspace{7mm}
\par
\pagestyle{fancy}

\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aside: `phv` gives an Helvetica clone, not Arial. Of course, many typophiles regard Arial as a weak, undistinguished copy of Helvetica. Thus, your document may be better off (admittedly every so slightly...) by you employing Helvetica and not Arial...

Comment: Incidentally, what are you trying to achieve by redefining `\sfdefault`, repeatedly?

Comment: Another aside: The commands `\large` and `\huge` -- as well as `\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize`, `\small`, `\normalsize`, `\Large`, and `\LARGE` -- are switches, i.e., they do not take arguments. Writing `\large{blurb}` is no different from just writing`\large blurb`. To confine the scope of `\large`, you must write `{\large blurb}`.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\large{\textbf{ABSTRACT should be arial 12}}}` is nothing that should appear in a LaTeX document. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You don't have any section headings or sections at all.

Comment: thanks everyone I implemented Mico code and works a treat. The use of sections and  and sectsy pacakage was a much better way to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've tried to simplify your code. Note the use of the `sectsty` package and its `\sectionfont` macro, and of `\section*` and `\section`, to pursue the simplification.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[vmargin=1.25in,hmargin=1.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{newtxtext}           % Times Roman
\usepackage[scaled=0.86]{helvet} % Helvetica

\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\large\sffamily}

\begin{document}
\raggedright

\hrule
\begin{center}
\huge\bfseries\sffamily Title is using arial
\end{center}
\hrule

\section*{ABSTRACT now uses arial}

Correctly using Times Roman 

\section{INTRODUCTION now uses arial}

Correctly using Times Roman

\section{METHODOLOGY now uses arial}

Correctly using Times Roman 
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico thats great it looks exactly like I would like and much cleaner code also ! Ive used \sections before but thought I needed to use the renew command to get the font to apply to the sections only. Many thanks thats two questions answered in one day on here - v impressed !

Comment: @cfr — Thanks. I’ve changed `times` to `newtxtext`.